# pubring.gpg and pubring.gpg~ at install - why?

Tags: gnupg

I've just installed GPG Suit and have pubring.gpg and pubring.gpg~ in ~/.gnupg.  Why?  Thank you.

```
~  cd .gnupg/
~/.gnupg  ls -a
.
..
gpg-agent.conf
gpg.conf
pubring.gpg
pubring.gpg~
secring.gpg
trustdb.gpg
```

Comment: Have a look at `pubring.gpg~`'s contents using `gpg --list-packets ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg`. What is it's file size and modification date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tilde is a common suffix for file backups.

This file is a backup of your public keys, used by GPG to avoid corrupting your keys when you modify them.

You can safely delete it, but it will be recreated the next time you use the program to modify the pubring.

[Source.](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2014-June/049920.html)

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for